# Dynamic mapping with SQL

Tags: sql, dictionary

I have an SQL db which contains a table of license plate numbers (`plates`), a table of parking lots (`places`), and a table corresponding one to the other over time (`parking`), each row placing a specific vehicle plate in a specific place at a particular time.

```
create table parking (
    plateid integer,
    placeid integer,
    time_period integer
);
```

This means each row as a whole is unique but the plate/place combinations are not.
I need to count how many times each plate appears in each place.  There are an indeterminate number of both, so I cannot maintain a table per place and simply count the entries.

This is easy enough using a general purpose programming language applied to the list.  Is there a way to do it with straight SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by both plate and place and count occurrences:

```
SELECT place_id, place_id, count(*)
FROM parking
GROUP BY place_id, plate_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select plate_id, place_id, count(*)
from parking
group by plate_id, place_id;
```

Comment: Yep, didn't realize 'group by' had this recursive/nesting property.

Comment: @CodeClown42 . . . There is no "nesting".  It is just using two keys.